# How do I deliver ready-to-run software?

Tags: python

Recently I've been developing Python code as a freelancer. I've mostly worked on social media bots, my usual way of delivering the code is as a Python script for people to run on their compilers. However, I've started to run into people that lack the technical knowledge of installing modules and running the code that way. How do I create a package like software and deliver it in a way that can be ready-to-run and users don't have to download anything extra? Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: You might have to deliver the app with a web interface. So you’ll have your script and also a simple route hosted on a domain they own. Make sure it’s their servers and everything. Make sure it runs and turn over all the logins to them

Comment: The fact that there is no easy answer to the question is one of Python's biggest weaknesses. You basically have to use a tool for each OS you are targeting and some of them require you use that OS to use that tool.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). It is a wrapper that converts your script into an executable, so the user can run it without needing to install any python libraries.

Alternatives to py2exe are:

1. [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) - the advantage of using this is that it lets you build executables in formats other than exe, if you want to make your program run on non-Windows platforms, for example.
2. [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - this is also another cross-platform alternative.

Comment: that would only work on platform that can run .exe files, though

Comment: @njzk2 I have edited my answer to include alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be (as stated in the previous answer) is to use exe converters, but that wouldn't be as effective if you target Mac and Linux users as well.

My solution is going to take you a little more time, but it will be worth it. Here goes:

Please learn Angular JS, or some other framework (I prefer Angular). Once you know that, you can easily develop a web app for your project, and add your Python to that.

The good news is, there are lots of tutorials for this, such as https://codehandbook.org/creating-a-web-app-using-angularjs-python-mongodb/ (also teaches you mongodb) Anyways, you can find other tutorials on your own.

You could of course, I guess, build it into a mobile app, but I think web app would be easier.